# How to get claims or JWT when using generated API interface with Spring Boot REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to use the openapi-generator plugin with my Spring Boot REST controller to manage the API interface, but from what I can see, there is no way to use the generated interfaces if I also need access to the JWT or claims.

With Spring, the claims and token are accessible by adding annotated parameters to the controller method. The parameters work wonderfully except that if I'm generating the interface from an OpenAPI specification, there is no way to add these parameters without modifying the generated code.

Am I missing something?

Is there a way to get to the JWT and claims without adding a parameter?

Is there a way to tell the generator to add additional parameters that won't show up in the API?

Comment: **Do not** allow a code generator (especially OpenAPI Generator) to create your controller signatures for you for exactly this reason. (My preferred compromise is to generate a client implementation and use that in tests to make sure everything matches.)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4680#issuecomment-656199687) helps. I used `(Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`